# wp_query post does not show data accurately

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I was created a custom post type. Now I want to retrieve data from that type post. My query_posts function does not recognize my exact post type. If there any post in POSTS that retrieve.

**Custom post type code is :**

```
 function wp_custom_post(){
    $wpargs=array(
    'public'=>true,
    'label'=> 'Slide',
    'labels'=>array(
        'name' => 'Slides',
        'singular_name'=>'Slide',
        'add_new' => 'Add new Slide'
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'     )
  );
  register_post_type('slider',$wpargs);
}

add_action('init', 'wp_custom_post');
```

**thumbnail image part code:**

```
add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'audio', 'video'));
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('slide-image',920,720,true);
```

**Data Retrieve/Show Code:**

```
      <?php query_posts(
                    array(
                        'post-type' => 'slider',
                        'post_per_page'=>4
                    )
                );?>
                <?php while (have_posts()):the_post();?>
                <div class="da-slide">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                    <?php the_excerpt();?>

                    <a href="#" class="da-link button">Read more</a>
                    <div class="da-img">

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('slide-image');?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="da-arrows">
                        <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                        <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;?>
                <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Please use "post_type" instead  "post-type".

Comment: Also use 'posts_per_page' instead of 'post_per_page'.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `post_type` Instead of of `post-type` and try the code below for fetching the custom posts:

```
<?php query_posts(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'slider',
    'post_per_page'=>4
    )
);?>
```